# CMAKE specifying different source directories

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake

I have the following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(azure)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Og -ggdb")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pipe -fmax-errors=2 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-deprecated-declarations $ENV{EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ../run)
set(local_lib_path "/Users/User1/Downloads/")

include_directories("src")
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB azure_sources src/*.cpp src/module/*/*.cpp)

file(GLOB test_sources src/*.cpp src/util/*.cpp src/module/*/*.cpp src/test/*)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework timer REQUIRED)
add_executable(sim_test ${test_sources})
target_link_libraries(sim_test ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY} ${Boost_TIMER_LIBRARY})
```

Due to permission issues, I have installed boost and gcc/g++ in folders other than the default. Currently the above cmake file tries to pick the compiler and the boost library from the default (/usr/bin/), which have older versions.

So I just wanted to ask how do I specify those new boost & gcc folders in the above cmake file? (I think some compiler etc paths are set by default in cmake, and I want to overwrite those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Specifying compiler version:**

Look in the [Compilers and Tools](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools) section for information on how to specify which compiler to use.

Namely, `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`

These are specified on the command line when invoking `cmake`:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-5.1
```

**Finding libraries in non-standard locations:**

The [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_library.html) takes a `PATHS` parameter, allowing you to specify where to search.

Alternatively, [`find_package` for boost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html)  takes a `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` parameter which can help you with specifying where to look.

---

Here is a little helper function which allows you to search for a static or shared library anywhere in your filesystem.

Usage is as follows:

```
find_static_lib(
    libname 
    LIB_NAME 
    PATHS
        /my/path/to/lib)
```

This would search for `libname.a` in `/my/path/to/lib` and if found, store the result in `${LIB_NAME}`

Source:

```
function(do_find_lib LIB_NAME SUFFIX OUT)
    # - searches for a library with a given suffix, optionally in paths
    #
    # arguments:
    # LIB_NAME lib_name
    # SUFFIX   suffix
    # OUT      output variable
    # PATHS    search paths*

    # parse arguments
    set(options)
    set(values)
    set(lists   PATHS)
    cmake_parse_arguments(FIND "${options}" "${values}" "${lists}" "${ARGN}")

    set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${SUFFIX})

    find_library(
        FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX} 
        ${LIB_NAME}
        PATHS
            ${FIND_PATHS}
        )

    if(NOT FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX})
        message(SEND_ERROR "unable to find library ${LIB_NAME}")
    endif()

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND_${LIB_NAME}${SUFFIX}} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()

#####################################################################################

function(find_static_lib LIB_NAME OUT)
    # arguments:
    # LIB_NAME lib_name
    # OUT      output variable
    # PATHS    search paths*

    # parse arguments
    set(options)
    set(values)
    set(lists   PATHS)
    cmake_parse_arguments(FIND "${options}" "${values}" "${lists}" "${ARGN}")

    if (WIN32 OR MSVC)
        set(SUFFIX ".lib")
    elseif (UNIX)
        set(SUFFIX ".a")
    endif()      

    do_find_lib(
        ${LIB_NAME} 
        ${SUFFIX} 
        FOUND 
        PATHS
            ${FIND_PATHS})

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()

#####################################################################################

function(find_shared_lib LIB_NAME OUT)
    # arguments:
    # LIB_NAME lib_name
    # OUT      output variable
    # PATHS    search paths*

    # parse arguments
    set(options)
    set(values)
    set(lists   PATHS)
    cmake_parse_arguments(FIND "${options}" "${values}" "${lists}" "${ARGN}")

    if (WIN32 OR MSVC)
        set(SUFFIX ".dll")
    elseif (UNIX)
        set(SUFFIX ".so")
    endif()      

    do_find_lib(
        ${LIB_NAME} 
        ${SUFFIX} 
        FOUND 
        PATHS
            ${FIND_PATHS})

    set(${OUT} ${FOUND} PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler setup is not the responsibility of CMake files; it must happen before CMake runs. CMake is designed so that it assumes it's running in an environment correctly configured for the build tools you want to use.

This means you should set environment variables like `CC` and `CXX` (and any others you need such as `PATH`) *before* running CMake. CMake will then pick up the compiler based on this environment.

If you've already configured with a certain environment (path to compiler etc.) and want to change that, the safest way is to nuke the binary directory and start over. You might get away with just blowing away `CMakeCache.txt` and the `CMakeFiles` directory, but I wouldn't consider that 100% safe.

Answer (score 1):

### Non-standard compiler setup

You **can** change the compiler paths within your `CMakeLists.txt`, but it's finicky and not recommended. The correct way to change your CMake compiler is create and specify what is called a toolchain file. The toolchain file is only run once and has the same syntax and commands available as CMakeLists.txt.

For example, I have a `clang_toolchain.cmake` file:

```
SET( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )

FIND_FILE( CLANG_C_BIN clang | NAMES clang-3.4 clang-3.5
           PATHS /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin
           HINTS ENV PATH )
FIND_FILE( CLANG_CXX_BIN clang++ | NAMES clang++-3.4 clang++-3.5
           PATHS /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin
           HINTS ENV PATH )
MARK_AS_ADVANCED( CLANG_C_BIN CLANG_CXX_BIN )

SET( CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CLANG_C_BIN} )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CLANG_CXX_BIN} )
```

This looks in the normal places, but you could just easily modify it to search for a locally installed copy of gcc and g++:

```
SET( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )

FIND_FILE( C_BIN gcc
           PATHS ~/local/bin )
FIND_FILE( CXX_BIN g++
           PATHS ~/local/bin )
MARK_AS_ADVANCED( C_BIN CXX_BIN )

SET( CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${C_BIN} )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CXX_BIN} )
```

which expects your copies of `gcc` and `g++`, respectively, to be located in `~/local/bin/`.

You can ( and must if you are using a toolchain ) specify a toolchain when you create the cache.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:PATH={PATH_TO_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} {PATH_TO_CMakeLists.txt}
```

### Non-standard Boost location

Locating boost libraries in a non-standard location is a supported part of Kitware's own find script for boost. Try setting `BOOST_ROOT` or `BOOSTROOT` prior to calling `find_package( Boost )`.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#module:FindBoost